# Extracting data from json and inserting into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, json

I try to extract data from a JSON string and insert into a SQL Server table. But I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Here is my code

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '{
 "id" : 2,
 "firstName": "John",
 "lastName": "Smith",
 "isAlive": true,
 "age": 25,
 "dateOfBirth": "2015-03-25T12:00:00" 
 }'

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
     WITH (id int, firstName nvarchar(50), lastName nvarchar(50),
           age int, dateOfBirth datetime2)
```

Comment: You forgot isAlive parameter in sql query

Comment: Check that the server is running SQL Server 2016. Older versions do not support `OPENJSON`.

Answer (score -1):

You correct syntax:

`OPENJSON` function that transforms JSON document to rowset

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '{
 "id" : 2,
 "firstName": "John",
 "lastName": "Smith",
 "isAlive": true,
 "age": 25,
 "dateOfBirth": "2015-03-25T12:00:00"
 }';

SELECT *   
FROM OPENJSON(@json)  
;WITH (id int,  firstName nvarchar(50), lastName nvarchar(50), isAlive bit, age int, dateOfBirth datetime2)
```

Comment: Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.